# IIS asp.net core 6 "DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

I am working on asp net core 6 app that uses unmanaged code located on a dll that is in program files x86

I install visual studio 2022 and run the app, and runs good. But when i deploy on iis, it show me that error

DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MGWServicios.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

I try the next:

- Install the visual c++ 2015 redistributable packs from 2010 to 2019
- run the app pool on localservice, localnetwork...
- give permision to the app poll to folder where is the dll
- Copy the file in same directory where is published the site

Nothing has worked.

EDIT

- I enable 32 bits mode

Comment: As IIS runs your code differently, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3, you need to make sure that the resolution of that native library works for your IIS configuration. For example, if this library is somewhere under 32 bit Program Files, you need to make sure that path is part of `PATH` environment variable. There are other ways to control from where a library is loaded and that's what you should explore further.

Comment: @LexLi How do I add  the file in the `PATH` ?
I add some env variables in the editor config, to show the errors, but I do not know where I need to put the dll Path in the editor

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, it seems you want to call the X86 dll inside the IIS.

Now the IIS is using the X64 by default.

I suggest you could modify the IIS application pool settings as below to enable 32-bit mode and try again.

If this isn't work, I suggest you could check your server's assembly cache to check if this dll is inside it or not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have alreary try it, the dll is 32 bits, but did not work

Comment: Please tell me how you host your core application inside the IIS, do you use Virtual directory?

Comment: I just deploy with the  visual studio publish to iis, I am not using virtual directory